# Why does a reference pointing to an object removed by the garbage collector not return null?

Tags: java, queue

I recently implemented a class called "Queue" in Java. It basically consists of the following functions, properties/attributes and classes:

```
Queue<ContentType>
    QueueNode => a private class inside public Queue
        ContentType content => a private reference to the content of a QueueNode
        QueueNode nextNode => a private reference to the next node
        QueueNode contains some functions like setNext(), getNext() and getContent() (returns the data of the node as ContentType)
    QueueNode head => the head node (first) of the queue (a reference)
    QueueNode tail => the tail (last) node of the queue (a reference)
    Queue contains some functions like enqueue(), size(), isEmpty() and dequeue().
```

The **dequeue()** functions looks like following:

```
public void dequeue() {
    if (!this.isEmpty()) {
        head = head.getNext();
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Again to the queue, [this picture explains everything pretty well](http://sibi-leo.de/wiki/images/Queue_ab_Abi2017.png)

What I thought and what my book says, is that after removing a ***QueueNode*** with **Queue.dequeue()**, the former first node will be removed automatically be the *garbage collector* of the Java-Runtime-environment (JRE) as there is no reference to the former first node anymore.

So I built another function within another class that implements a queue (as a static variable): (The queue is of type ***Held***)

```
static Held heileNaechstenHeld() {
    if (wartebank.isEmpty()) return null;
    Held held = wartebank.front();
    wartebank.dequeue();
    return held;
}
/*
Just to make it clear, wartebank is of type Queue<Held>.
*/
```

So in my opinion, this function should always return null. Instead, when I call this function after adding an element of type ***Held*** to the queue, it returns this object (held). 
Why is that?

The expected behavior was that the function **heileNaechstenHeld()** would always return *null*. I thought that the fix would be to *copy* the whole object, e.g. create a new object with the *new* keyword and return that one.

Comment: Garbage Collector removes objects which have no references to the object. By fetching it before the `dequeue`, you're referencing it. Why would the GC get rid of it if there's still a reference pointing to it? Also, you can't really control when the GC runs, so you can't guarantee it will run just after the `dequeue` instruction.

Comment: So does that mean that it could possibly run before, so that it may return null? @AntonH

Comment: No. The GC only frees memory when no pointer is pointing to it. You specifically said: `Held held = wartebank.front();` which points to the memory. Why should the GC clear the memory when a pointer is pointing to it?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your comments (both of you). Could you let me know why my question is down voted? I am more ore less new to Java as I told, so I tried my best to make this question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the Garbage Collector's **root objects** are local variables in an any thread method stack. So, an object will not be garbage collected in the bounds of this method, because here is a **strong reference** to it inside the active method. But if you are going to ignore this method's return value, in the next few GC's collecting cycles, this object will be collected (because no more references to it left) and memory from it's storing will be reclaimed.